# Karate - How to set HTTP status to variable from When step?

Tags: karate, http-status-code-204

I'm calling a rest service through Karate API with DELETE method. When the service is executed, I am getting HTTP status 204 which is expected.

```
When method DELETE
Then status 204
```

Test is passing, but I need to store that status for furhter steps in test scenario.

When I want to set this status to other variable, like:

```
    When method DELETE
    * def responseStatus = status
    Then status 204
```

test failed because:

```
* def responseStatus = status
js failed:
>>>>
01: status
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "status" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

How can I reuse the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status code is already given to you as a "magic" variable called `responseStatus`. Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#responsestatus

So you certainly can do things like this:

```
* if (responseStatus == 204) karate.call('some.feature')
```